# What Soviet-era space-related film is this Nick Stevens tweet referring to?

Tags: history, space-art

@antzi's [post](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43955143#43955143) in chat lead me to the Nick Stevens' [Twitter account](https://twitter.com/runnymonkey) in which I found the following 9-Apr-2018 [Tweet](https://twitter.com/runnymonkey/status/983390009041604609):

> Soviet film, dramatized version of #Korolev and #Gagarin with the ADU-1000 Pluton deep space antenna.

and this [Tweet](https://twitter.com/runnymonkey/status/983383133184839684) links to several newer photos of the ADU-1000 array.

> Some more photos of the ADU-1000 "Pluton" Soviet radio antenna.
>   The base turntable is taken from a battleship big gun.
>   The big spine under the dishes is made from joined submarine hulls.
>
> The ADU-1000 Pluton deep space antenna is the see-once and never forget array of dishes at the [Pluton complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluton_(complex)), and [Korolev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergei_Korolev) and [Gagarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuri_Gagarin) of course refer to the historical rocket scientist and astronaut of the early Soviet space program.

**QUESTION:** What Soviet-era film is this Nick Stevens tweet referring to?

According to the Wikipedia article:

> The Pluton complex supported all the Soviet space programs until 1978, when the Yevpatoria RT-70 radio telescope was built, then the Pluton became a backup system for the RT-70. The Pluton complex was the world's highest capacity deep space communication system prior to Goldstone in 1966.
>
> In 1961 it performed one of the world's first radar detection of the planet Venus. In June 1962 it performed the world's first successful radar detection of the planet Mercury[1](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43955143#43955143) . In February 1963 it performed successful radar detection of the planet Mars. In September–October 1963 it performed successful radar detection of the planet Jupiter.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: The more direct route would be to ask Nick Stevens by replying to that tweet...

Comment: @Hobbes in this case SE came through in 62 minutes. *Stack Exchange Rocks!* Also, I don't mess with FaceBook, Twitter, etc. My phone doesn't even have apps beyond what Apple put there originally. Gmail, SE, and SMS keep me plenty distracted as it is!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That frame is from the movie "[Taming of the Fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taming_of_the_Fire)". In Russian: "Укрощение огня".

You can watch it on Mosfilm website:

- http://cinema.mosfilm.ru/films/film/Ukroshenie-ognya/ukroschenie-ognya-1/

According to [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0069434/):

> Ukroshcheniye ognya (1972), June 1973 (USA), 2h 46min
>
> About Russian space program and missile industry, and it's founder Sergei P. Korolev, from the 1920s to the first man in space in 1961.
>
> **Director, Writer:** Daniil Khrabrovitsky
>
> **Stars:** Kirill Lavrov, Ada Rogovtseva, Igor Gorbachyov

Comment: and you can [find it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ttft3jIPJGE) with english subtitles on youtube

Comment: Thanks for your speedy answer, I'm really looking forward to seeing it! I've added a bit of formatting, and some info from IMDB.

Comment: @horsh thanks for the YouTube link. Although imperfect, the subtitles are very helpful.

Comment: 2 minute episode from this movie with ADU-1000  antenna at the First Site of Center Deep space communications https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gVE7yMahGdA